# String to JsonObject using Gson java

Tags: json, spring, gson

I really want to use `org.json.JSONObject`. But some case doesn't work on my private project. So I currently use `com.google.code.gson`.
I can't parse this string.

```
"{ \"id\": \"\", \"title\": \"\", \"message\": \"\"}"
```

Here is my code:

```
JsonElement jsonElementFormat = data.parse(format);
JsonObject jsonFormat = jsonElementFormat.getAsJsonObject();
```

this code get this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "{ \"id\": \"\", \"title\": \"\", \"message\": \"\"}"
```

So I tried this code.

```
format = format.replace("\\\"", "'");
JsonElement jsonElementFormat = data.parse(format);
JsonObject jsonFormat = jsonElementFormat.getAsJsonObject();
```

and this code get exception.
What I should do??
help me!

Comment: and, I tried ``` format = format.replace("\"", "'");. But doesn't work

Comment: What is a `data` object type?